# Fuso horário em JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var hora = d.getHours();
    if (_userdata["user_level"] > 0) {
        console.log("Você é da staff e pode acessar o fórum.");
    } else if (hora >= 22 || hora <= 7) { 
        $('body').html('<div class="forumfechado">Fórum atualmente fechado. Volte mais tarde.</div>');
    };
});
```

Esse código "fecha" a webpage entre as 22 e as 7. Porem, ele pega o horário do PC e qualquer pessoa que altere o horário do PC pode acessar a webpage. Como eu faço para que isso não aconteça? Poderia fazer utilizando um GMT/Fuso Horário? Se sim, como?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso não é possível com javascript, você precisa de alguma linguagem que rode no servidor (php por exemplo) para garantir a eficácia da trava.

Comment: não tenho conhecimento suficiente para orientar com precisão o Fábil Miguel, porém acredito que seja possível sim com Javascript, utilizando algo assim -> http://help.exacttarget.com/pt-BR/documentation/exacttarget/conteudo/javascript_do_servidor/guia_de_sintaxe/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/funcoes_javascript_do_servidor_datetime/

Comment: Eu acredito que dessa maneira vai dar um trabalho muitíssimo maior, e continuará sem muita eficácia.

Comment: Tudo certo! Vou optar por deixar como está mesmo. obrigado.